# how to read same data from two sheet then subtract the data using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need some formula or function for subtraction from another sheet using same id(barcode).

When you click button save or submit then the data(Quantity) will change using a  macro.

[stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCl35.jpg)[image]

[invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miRRg.jpg)
[image: ![enter image description here]

I want to know how to subtract data from invoice to stock sheet:

```
answer = invoice (Quantity) - stock (quantity)
```

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub inv()


  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim i As Long
  Dim A As Long
  Dim B As Range
  Dim rng_dest As Range
  Dim RANGE1 As Range
  Dim RANGE2 As Range


    'for subtract quantity in invoice and stock
    Dim num1 As Integer
    Dim num2 As Integer
    Dim ans As Integer
    Dim Stock As Long
    Dim invoice As Range
    Dim stk As Range




 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    num1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8:B37").Value
    num2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("STOCK").Range("B8:B").Value

    ans
     If num2 = num1 Then
      ans = num2 - num1





  'Check if invoice # is found on sheet "Invoice data"

  i = 1

  Do Until Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = ""

    If Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("H3").Value Then

      'Ask overwrite invoice #?

      If MsgBox("Invoice Already Exist.. Do you want to Overwrite.?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

        Exit Sub

      Else

        Exit Do

      End If

    End If

    i = i + 1

  Loop


  i = 1

  Set rng_dest = Sheets("Invoice data").Range("D:D")
    Set RANGE1 = Sheets("Invoice data").Range("G:G")

  'Delete rows if invoice # is found

  Do Until Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = ""

    If Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("H3").Value Then

      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete

      i = 1

    End If

    i = i + 1

  Loop

  ' Find first empty row in columns D:G on sheet Invoice data

  Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0

    i = i + 1
     Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(RANGE1.Rows(i)) = 0

    i = i + 1
    Loop

  Loop

      'Copy range B16:I38 on sheet Invoice

  Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B8:B37")
    Set RANGE2 = Sheets("Invoice").Range("D8:D37")


  ' Copy rows containing values to sheet Invoice data

    For A = 1 To rng.Rows.Count


    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(A)) <> 0 Then

      rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(A).Value

       If WorksheetFunction.CountA(RANGE2.Rows(A)) <> 0 Then

      RANGE1.Rows(i).Value = RANGE2.Rows(A).Value


      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("H3").Value

      'Copy Date

      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("B" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("H2").Value

      'Copy Company name

      Sheets("Invoice data").Range("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Invoice").Range("B1").Value



      i = i + 1
    End If
       End If




  Next A

  MsgBox ("Invoice saved!")


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("Invoice").Range("H3").Value = _
    Sheets("Invoice").Range("H3").Value + 1




End Sub







Sub Formc()

  UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: Google `VLOOKUP`, you don't need VBA for this.

Comment: hello sir
how to make the deduction calculation from  Quantity in Stock sheet after click a save button ?
for your information the Quantity that I refer to is at Invoice sheet  should linking to Stock Sheet .

Answer (score 2):

This kind of scenario is not what Excel was built for. It can be done, but there are many dangers in getting things wrong because the dependencies are not understood.

First of all, the Quantity column should be relative to a starting stock count, so you can use the starting count as the base level and then subtract any numbers of stock referenced in invoices.

I'd add a new column "Starting Stock Balance" with the initial stock count for each item.

Then you can create a column with current stock that takes into account the starting balance and subtracts the sum of all items with the same code from the invoice sheet. If starting stock balance is in column D and current stock should be calculated in column E, use a formula along the lines of this:

```
=D2-Sumifs(Invoice!$D:$D,Invoice!$C:$C,$B2)
```

In words: take the value in D2 and subtract the sum of all items you can find in Invoice column D where Invoice column C is the same description as stock sheet column B in the current row.

Adjust cell ranges and sheet names to your situation.

Despite claims from @vacip that this can be done with Vlookup, it can't.

Edit: Or if you want to base the formula on the bar code instead of the description, use

```
=D2-Sumifs(Invoice!$D:$D,Invoice!$B:$B,$A2)
```

Comment: Well, based on the example from OP, the barcode is unique, yet you assume they are not unique. This decides if you can use VLOOKUP or not  - why not ask OP rather than arguing?

Comment: The bar code is unique in the stock sheet, because each stock item exists only one in that table. As for the Invoice sheet: an item can be ordered many times by different people, so the bar code will not be unique in the Invoice sheet.

Comment: in invoice table there are 1 button to save the data in invoice  then i need to know how and what code to use...to subtract quantity in table stock.. tq =)

Comment: And which part of the code are you having problems with? You did not post any code or mention any button before.

Comment: sorry,I already post there...can you help me?? i want to put in there, when you click button save then the data will save in invoice data (another sheet) then will subtract quantity in stock Sheet..